# Google Analytics - Segment/Filter View - Based on Custom Attribute

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, segment, gtag.js

I am not sure of the best way to handle this, however I am sure it is possible to implement with Google Analytics.

I currently have 1 Google Analytics account with all the data.

I would like to create 3 additional "views" within Google Analytics to filter each part of my app accordingly.

The sections are:

- the landing pages `landing` (sales pitch)
- the application pages `app` (the product we offer)
- the customer portal pages `portal` (the product we offer to our user which thier users view).

So dimensions/views (unsure of the terminology here) are;
`landing` `app` and `portal`.

Currently I am using code like the following;

```
function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments)
}
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [], gtag("js", new Date), gtag("config", "UA-XXXXXXXXX-1", {
    custom_map: {
        dimension1: "website_segment"
    },
    website_segment: "landing"
});
```

I was then expecting to see these values in;

```
View > Filters > Custom
```

However they don't exist.

Please note:

1. I **do not** wish to utilize separate GA accounts to achieve this.
2. I cannot utilize the URL scheme with regex to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your need, it absolutely seems feasible. You collect your data in one Analytics property, and you would like to create separate views for various site content, where content is identified by a custom dimension, instead of the page path.

**First**, make sure, you have **enabled custom dimension 1** in your property settings. As you are collecting this data on hit level, you need to set the custom dimension to hit level as well.

[image]

**Second**, you need to deploy your code to **send this data to Google Analytics**. I assume, you can substitute the proper value (landing/app/portal) for the `website_segment` key. Please let me know, if this is also part of your question, how to assign the proper value to the defined custom dimension.

To check if data is sent, you can use Google Analytics Debugger Chrome extension, or you can inspect the call to www.google-analytics.com in developer console / Network tab, whether cd1 parameter is set.

To verify if data is available in Google Analytics, the easiest way is to open the Behavior / Content / All pages report, and to add your custom dimension as a secondary dimension for a period, which should already contain data.

**Third**, you need to create your new views and your **filters** within Google Analytics. Please note, that you won't see any available values here, but you can still select your custom dimension, and define a filter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Custom Dimensions should be available in your list of fields when you're setting up a filter for your GA view.

It looks like you're sending info to GA with the code you provided, but have you defined the Custom Dimension in your GA settings? You'll need to do that as a first step.

Access `Property > Custom Definitions > Custom Dimensions`, add a custom dimension, and set the scope (you'll want a Hit scope for your use case). Then ensure your code is configured to send to the dimension you just created.

See https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828#Lifecycle for an overview of Custom Dimensions - though it looks like the code snippets there are out-of-date, depending on which version of GA you're using.